# Is there a subfield $F$ of $\Bbb R$ such that there is an embedding $F(x) \hookrightarrow F$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I believe that for any subfield $F$ of $\Bbb R$, with finite degree of transcendence over $\Bbb Q$, the field of rational fractions in one variable $F(x)$ can't be embedded in $F$. However the situation can be different for those with infinite degree of transcendence over $\Bbb Q$.

I [know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465631) that $F(x)$ always embeds in $\Bbb C$. Actually $\Bbb C(x)$ embeds in $\Bbb C^{[1]}$.
I only know that if $j:F(x) \hookrightarrow F$ denotes a field morphism, then $j(x)$ is transcendental over $\Bbb Q$.

Here is an idea for $F=\Bbb R$. Let's take a transcendence basis $T$ of $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q$ ([which](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendence_degree#Examples) has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$) and complete it into a (linear algebra) basis $B$ of $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q$. Then $T$ and $T \cup \{x\}$ ($x$ is the indeterminate) have the same cardinality, we can pick a bijection $b:T \cup \{x\}\to T$. Then we could try to build some $j : \Bbb R(x)=\Bbb Q(B \cup \{x\}) \to \Bbb Q(B)=\Bbb R$...

Any hint would be appreciated!

---

$^{[1]}$ A nice example from [heptagon](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/357340/heptagon) shows the existence of a subfield $L \subset \Bbb C$ such that $L(x) \cong L$. Indeed, we can embed $L=\Bbb R(x_1,x_2,\dots)$ in $\Bbb C$.

Comment: How can $F$ be equal to $\mathbb{R}$ if the trancsendence degree over $\mathbb{Q}$ is finite?

Comment: @heptagon: I consider any subfield of $\Bbb R$. My "belief" is related to the ones with finite degree of transcendence, but my general question also deals with the ones with infinite degree of transcendence.

Comment: Maybe there is no subfield $F \subset \Bbb R$ such that $F(x) \hookrightarrow F$ (even the ones with infinite degree of transcendence over $\Bbb Q$), but I'm not sure how to (dis)prove it.

Comment: First of all, for those with finite transcendence degree embeddings are not possible: $F(x)$ has greater transc.degree than $F$, so there should be an algebraically independent subset of $F(x)$ sent to an algebraically dependent subset of $F$ under embedding.

Comment: @heptagon: ok, just to be sure for instance we can never have $k(X_0,X_1) \cong k(X_1)$ (as fields) where $k$ is any field, because the transcendence degrees over $k$ are $2 ≠1$? Even for $k = \Bbb Q(X_2,X_3,X_4,\dots)$ ; doesn't the map fixing $\Bbb Q$ and sending $X_j$ to $X_{j-1}$ give a field isomorphism $k(X_1) \to k(X_0,X_1)$ ?

Comment: No, this is important that $k$ is rationals here, because in general $k$ must not be sent into $k$ under embeddings.

Comment: @heptagon: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44110/discussion-between-watson-and-heptagon), if you don't mind. I would have a few more questions related to transcendence degree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've found an example, thanks to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1896239) answer. We pick a subset $\{x_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ of pairwise distinct elements of a transcendence basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ (this is possible since a transcendence basis of $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q$ [has](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendence_degree#Examples) cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$).

Then the subfield $F = \Bbb Q(x_1, \dots, x_n, \dots)$ satisfies $F \cong F(X) \cong F(X,Y) \cong \cdots$ (as fields), so in particular $F(X)$ embeds in $F$.

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103177) for the transcendence degree.